# Is there a way to know how much time is spent in Gurobi usercuts?

Tags: optimization, time, julia, julia-jump

I am using JuMP Mathematical Optimization Interface user cuts Callbacks with Gurobi

```
MOI.set(m, MOI.UserCutCallback(), callback_benders_usercuts)
```

And I would like to know if there is a way to know how much time is spent in my usercut function `callback_benders_usercuts`?

```
usercuts_time = 0
callback_benders_usercuts(arguments)
    usercuts_time += time()
    # ... computing
    usercuts_time += time() - usercuts_time
    return
```

Doesn't work because, I think, `callback_benders_usercuts` is called at many nodes and my variable interconnects itself.

I get the following obviously incorrect:

```
 [ Info: Spent 1.614e9s in User cuts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want instead

```
callback_benders_usercuts(arguments)
    t = time()
    # ... computing
    usercuts_time += time() - t
    return
```